# How can I get pdf file of ibook in my application?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to open document file using swift 4. My requirement is that I want to use document picker. Using Document picker I can upload that file using my application.
In short in my app iIwant other documents like .pdf from device. i had try this .

```
func documentMenu(_ documentMenu: UIDocumentMenuViewController, didPickDocumentPicker documentPicker: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {
    documentPicker.delegate = self
    present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
     let myURL = urls
    print("import result : \(myURL)")
}

func documentPickerWasCancelled(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {
    print("view was cancelled")
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func dsds(_ sender: Any) {
    let importMenu = UIDocumentMenuViewController(documentTypes: [String(kUTTypePDF)], in: .import)
    importMenu.delegate = self
    importMenu.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
    self.present(importMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: "but not working as I want".. what is it doing that you dont want?

Comment: what do you mean @Scriptable

Comment: We do not know what the problem is, not working as I want does not tell us much. is there something your current code does not do that you want to? I dont think you can view the books that are in ibooks from another app, so if thats the issue then I dont think you can do it

Comment: yes there is book in other app & i want that in my app @Scriptable

Comment: Apps have their own sandboxed documents folder which is not accessible to other apps. You can't just browse the storage on the phone like you would in a desktop pc.